# Bind each item of ItemsSource to a different ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf

Run in a little trouble. I have a DataGrid, which is bound to a list of objects. One of the object properties is an Icon (which is a string).When displaying the object in the DataGrid - I have a ComboBox (which suppose to hold a static list of Icons). The thing which I dont know how to bind is the itemssource of the icons collection. Here is what I have so far: 
**XAML**

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgMenus"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Visibility="Collapsed"
              CanUserSortColumns="True"
              Style="{StaticResource DataGrid}">
    ...

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icon"
                            Width="Auto"  
                            IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Name="cbIconSelector"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}"   
                                  SelectionChanged="cbIconSelector_SelectionChanged"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding iconsLibrary}"
                                  SelectedIndex="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource FontAwesome_HTML_To_ComboBox_SelectedIndex}}"
                                  BorderThickness="0"
                                  Width="60"
                                  Height="30"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"
                                               Text="{Binding XML}"
                                               Margin="2"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    ...
    </DataGrid>
```

**C#**

```
dgMenus.ItemsSource = _viewmodel._menusForDisplay;
iconsLibrary = new FontAwesomeLibrary().icons;
```

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this? `"One of the object properties is and Icon (which is a string)`"

Comment: Sure. I have a class Menu. One of its properties is public string Icon { get; set; }. And the ItemsSource of the DataGrid is a collection of Menu objects.

Comment: If the list of icons is static, you could have them in a static resource and bind the ItemsSource to that.

Comment: Change the Source for your `ComboBox.ItemsSource` binding. Often I just use a `RelativeSource` and lookup `DataGrid.DataContext` and find some property on there. For example, I might have a class with `MyDataGridItems` and `MyComboBoxItems` as the DataContext, and I would bind `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `MyDataGridItems`, and use a RelativeSource binding to bind the `ComboBox ItemsSource` to `MyDataGrid.DataContext.MyComboBoxItems`. Another option you could use if you don't need selection capabilities is a Converter to convert your String to an Icon, and just display it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make it work was to set a Loaded event to the ComboBox and out there set the desired ItemsSource.